# Node shape when using networkx and gexf format

Tags: python, networkx, gephi

I am trying to customize a graph using networkX (for use in gexf format).  But I have not been able to set the shape of the node. 
Using the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440561/)

```
import sys
import urllib2
import networkx as nx
data = urllib2.urlopen('http://gexf.net/data/viz.gexf')
G = nx.read_gexf(data)

print G.node['a']

G.node['a']['viz']['position']['x']=10
G.node['a']['viz']['position']['y']=20

# now my addition 
G.node['a']["viz"]['shape'] = 'disc'

print G.node['a'] this seems to work
```

**but I can't write the file**

```
nx.write_gexf(G,sys.stdout)
```

the error is :

```
# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in the GEXF format writer.

Hopefully fixed now: https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/875